# Explicit toroidal compactification of Hilbert modular varieties

Tags: nt.number-theory, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, shimura-varieties, compactifications

Hirzebruch's construction of toroidal compactification of Hilbert modular surfaces is explicit, namely one can explicitly choose rational polyhedral cone decomposition in a sort of optimal way using convex hull/continued fractions. Is such an explicit theory available for higher degree totally real fields? If so, is there a reference?

Comment: Borisov and Gunnells consider partial toroidal resolutions for a particular example of a Hilbert modular threefold over a totally real cubic field in section 3 of [*On Hilbert modular threefolds of discriminant 49*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1820). They also mention Grundman's [*Explicit resolutions of cubic cusp singularities*](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2000-69-230/S0025-5718-99-01121-7/S0025-5718-99-01121-7.pdf), which might be closer to what you're looking for.